# Issue while deploying DB2 jars on project on jdk 1.5

Tags: db2, jarsigner

My java-application is currently connected to `oracle DB`, deployed on `Windows`. But when I am trying to connect the same to dB2 database it is giving me error as mentioned below:

> Exception in thread "Timer-6" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:240)
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193)
>           at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:305)
>           at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:216)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:341)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:406)
>           at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:752)
>           at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
>           at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
>           at com.pramati.util.loader.ProtonURLClassLoader.loadClass(ProtonURLClassLoader.java:404)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
>           at com.pramati.util.loader.ProtonURLClassLoader.loadClass(ProtonURLClassLoader.java:404)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
>           at com.pramati.util.loader.ProtonURLClassLoader.loadClass(ProtonURLClassLoader.java:404)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>           at com.infy.cis.license.LicenseTimer$RemindTask.run(LicenseTimer.java:95)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

I have used following db2 jars after signing them:

- db2jcc.jar,
- db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar,
- db2jcc_license_cu.jar.

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: You do not need the license files when connecting to a DB2 on Linux, UNIX or Windows. Where did you take the driver from?

Comment: Hi AngocA, they were installed as part of standard IBM Data studio client 4.1